# Event-Data Visualization in R, Very Simple Question i

Tags: r, time-series, visualization

this is a very simple question. Yet, I could not find an answer to it. I have a protest event data set, where each raw contains attributes of a particular protest event including the date of the event.

What I want to have a basic plot that has the date on the x axis. My date format in day-month-year and the dataset contains around 9000 entries. And I want to see the frequency of protest events. That is to say I want to understand during which times we see an increase in the number of protest events. How can I do that in R? It may look as simple as this one:  https://acleddata.com/acleddatanew/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/US2.png

Comment: You can do this with any plotting framework in R. I'd recommend either a histogram or a lineplot, like you have. If you want more help, you could provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Here are some examples with data.
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/128-plot-time-series-data-using-ggplot/

Comment: Oh thank you I have managed to do it with histogram as it does not require specifying y axis but could not do it with line it wants me to have a y variable

Comment: Maybe a density plot using a simple kernel. It will provide a sinuous curve and not a segmented one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

# generating a minimal sample as none is provided
# 200 dates randomly sampled 100 days around today
df <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+runif(200,-100,100))

ggplot(df)+
   geom_density(aes(x=date))
```